sitemap_generator + mobility
I can't figure out what the problem is.
I use systemmap_generator gems in conjunction with mobility and friendly_id.
Here is the sitemmap.rb file:
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "MY_HOST_NAME"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create_index = true

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  {uk: :ukrainian, ru: :russian}.each_pair do |locale, name|
    group(sitemaps_path: "sitemaps/#{locale}/", filename: name) do
      add root_path(locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily'
      add prices_path(locale: locale)
      add about_path(locale: locale)
      add contacts_path(locale: locale)
      add faq_path(locale: locale)
      add services_path(locale: locale)
      add articles_path(locale: locale)

      Article.friendly.find_each do |article|
        add article_path(article, locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily', lastmod: article.updated_at
      end
      Service.friendly.find_each do |service|
        add service_path(service, locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily', lastmod: service.updated_at
      end 
    end
  end
end

For the :uk locale everything is generated normally, but for another locale (:ru), links are not generated. Or rather, they are generated, but as for the :uk locale, i.e. without translation. Accordingly, Google does not find these pages and does not index them.
Here is sitemap.xml example for :uk locale:

And for :ru locale

Can anybody tell me what the problem is?
slug generates correct paths


I don't see anything that suggests mobility will translate the path to a given locale. So I would say this is functioning as expected. There appears to be a gem called route_translator that will provide this functionality.

Thanks, but: https://i.sstatic.net/rUEAuGUk.png - correct transcription in slug

I figured out. ))) Just need to set I18n.locale manualy. I18n.locale = locale

Just need to set locale manualy:
# Set the host name for URL creation
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://druzhba.biz.ua/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create_index = true

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  {uk: :ukrainian, ru: :russian}.each_pair do |locale, name|
    group(sitemaps_path: "sitemaps/#{locale}/", filename: name) do
      I18n.locale = locale - here was my problem
      add root_path(locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily'
      add prices_path(locale: locale)
      add about_path(locale: locale)
      add contacts_path(locale: locale)
      add faq_path(locale: locale)
      add services_path(locale: locale)
      add articles_path(locale: locale)

      Article.friendly.find_each do |article|
        add article_path(article, locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily', lastmod: article.updated_at
      end
    
      Service.friendly.find_each do |service|
        add service_path(service.slug, locale: locale), changefreq: 'daily', lastmod: service.updated_at
      end

    end
  end
end

